# How to get rid of for loop in my function?

Tags: python, numpy

```
y = numpy.zeros(len(data))
for i in range(len(data)):
    if i == 0:
        y[i] = (1.0-dec) * data[i]
    else:
        y[i] = (1.0-dec) * data[i] + (dec*y[i-1])

y
```

So for example I have

```
data = np.array([100,200,300,400,500])
dec = 0.1
```

output:

```
array([ 90.   , 189.   , 288.9  , 388.89 , 488.889])
```

But for a huge dataset of data the "for" loop will take a lot of time to execute, so I was seeking help from someone that can we optimize it using some function from numpy.

Comment: please explain what you mean by "getting rid" of the for loop? maybe explain what the code is supposed to do and why you used a for loop in the first place?

Comment: I think they mean how to vectorize it, but it would help to know what it's supposed to do first.

Comment: @Iguananaut yeah I mean how to vectorize.

Comment: you can use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) to optimize run time as it is.

Comment: @Iguananaut still don't understand it, can you write it down in my case?